# Java 2D array diagonals

Tags: java, arrays, bluej, diagonal

I wrote a program to try to solve the 8 queens problem and one part of it required me to test all of the forward and backward diagonals to make sure there were no conflicts. I got the backwards to work perfectly but this part of the forward one was returning true while I was testing and I really can't figure out why. And help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
class NonAttackingQueen {
  static char [][] board = { {'X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X'}, 
                             {'X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X'},
                             {'X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X'},
                             {'X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X'},
                             {'X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X'},
                             {'X','Q','X','X','X','X','X','X'},
                             {'Q','X','X','X','X','X','X','X'},
                             {'X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X'} };
public static boolean diagonalsClear () {
    int numQueens;
    boolean clear = true;
    for (int numSpots = 1; numSpots < 9; numSpots++) {
        numQueens = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < numSpots - 1; row++) {
            if (board[row][numSpots - 1 - row] == 'Q')
                numQueens++;
        }
        if (numQueens > 1) {
            clear = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    for (int numSpots = 7; numSpots > 0; numSpots--) {
        numQueens = 0;
        for (int row = 7; row > 7 - numSpots; row--) {
            if (board[row][15-row-numSpots] == 'Q')
                numQueens++;
        }
        if (numQueens > 1) {
            clear = false;
            break;
        }
      return clear;
    }
}
```

Comment: Firstly, its good practice to initialize variables `int numQueens=0`;, secondly, isDiagonalsClear() folllow Java convention for bool-returning functions.

Comment: If you change your ifs (numQueens > 1) to return false instead of writing to variable it should work fine. I think in your case clear is overwritten in second loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Little trick to solve this problem. It is obvious, that you have mistake with matrix `row` and `column` indices calculation, and your loops do not cover all cells in it. Easiest way to check it, just print it out to console. I can see, that you have problem with `for (int row = 0; row < numSpots - 1; row++)`. Firs iteration, when `numSpots=1` it skips this loop. Correct is `for (int row = 0; row <= numSpots - 1; row++)`.

Let me give you some notes about your example. I can see that two upper and lower part of the matrix you check with opposite direction, upper one you start with `row=0` and lower one - `col=0`. I think to do the same calculation is much better for understanding. You could decomposite you task into three simple once:

1. Check one single diagonal, starting with given `row` and `column`;
2. check upper diagonals;
3. check lower diagonals.

I think example below is more clear for reading:

```
private static boolean isDiagonalClear(int row, int col) {
    int total = 0;

    do {
        if (board[row--][col++] == 'Q')
            total++;
    } while (total <= 1 && row >= 0 && col < 8);

    return total <= 1;
}

public static boolean diagonalsClear() {
    for (int row = 0; row < 7; row++)
        if (!isDiagonalClear(row, 0))
            return false;

    for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++)
        if (!isDiagonalClear(7, col))
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: if the number is spots is 1 it doesn't really matter to check the diagonal for a second queen though does it?